# offline html5 app

Tags: html, html5

привет .
Решил протестировать возможность создания offline приложения

**index.html**

```
 <html manifest="cache.manifest">

 <img src="1.jpg" width="100" height="100" >
  <img src="2.jpg" width="100" height="100" >
```

**cache.manifest**

```
CACHE MANIFEST
index.html
global.css
1.jpg
2.jpg
```

Работаю на xampp. 
Запускаю приложение и вижу в консоле что идет создание кэша.
Затем при рефреше страници вижу что идет использование кэша.
Тушу сервер и приложение отлично работает.
Тепер вношу изменения в **index.html** на сервере и поднимаю сервер но при оновлении страници используется старая версия    index.html

почему не оновился кэш когда доступ к сети появился ? 
Можно ли принудительно оновить кэш/сбросить ?
Можно ли задать время хранения кэша ?

Answer (score 1):

Любое изменение содержимого файла манифеста приведёт к перезапросу. Для этого в нём пишут комментарий с версией приложения.

Подробнее: http://habrahabr.ru/post/151815/

Comment: добавил коментарий но не помогает...Вожможно єто справидливо если в нем нету файл index.html

Comment: @zloctb, почисти руками и попробуй ещё раз по инструкции.